# Is there a way to identify which windows/apps are open on which monitor?

Tags: macos, dock, mission-control

I have a Macbook with 2 external monitors attached and my Mission Control setup for Displays to have separate spaces.

[image]

Having recently switched over from Windows 10, one thing I miss significantly is the ability to quickly identify at a glance which app/window is present on which monitor.  In Windows 10, I can configure the taskbar such that it shows only the windows that are present on the given screen.  This allows me to quickly identify which app is open where.

I've been looking for a tool or a configuration in MacOS 12+ that allows me to do the same, but I can't seem to find anything.

Is there a setting that I haven't been able to find or a utility that I can add to present this information?  With the Dock only visible on a single monitor at a time, I would be happy to have some other visual indicator to allow me to quickly find my window.

Comment: What do you mean by you have "Mission Control setup for Displays to have separate spaces."? If you enable More Gestures under System Preference--> TrackPad --> check the box for Mission Control, you can then use three finger swipe up and three finger swipe left/right to see all windows in all displays and navigate through desktops(wokspaces) easily. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: If no trackpad, use control + up arrow to show Mission Control, control +  left/right arrow keys to move between desktops/workspaces.

Comment: @elegantcomplexity I've pasted the image of my Mission Control config to help explain. Using Mission Control is not practical as I don't know which screen my window/desktop is on and cannot be opened while already dragging things with the mouse. I was looking for a visual indicator (widget) that I could use to quickly identify at a single glance which window is where. As indicated, in W10, I can setup the taskbar to only show which windows are open on a given display - with each display "owning" its own taskbar. Was looking for something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try sliding three fingers upwards to show mission control. You can also then move your mouse pointer up top to get a preview of the other spaces on that screen, move the pointer to the other screen for similar previews.

If Mission Control does not show then follow @elegantcomplexity 's instructions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).